# Dúvida com passagem de parâmetro em uma Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um controle que recebe um ID e faz uma listagem, mais nesta página eu tenho um botão para retornar para a página anterior, então como ela também recebe um id, então como eu poderia passar este id de forma dinâmica?

Aqui eu estou retornando passando o ID 1 :
SelecionarModalidade/1

```
<div class="span6">
    <a href="@Url.Action("SelecionarModalidade/1", "Modalidade" )" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-hand-left">
    Retorno
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assim:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SelecionarModalidade", "Modalidade", new { id = 1 })" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-hand-left">
```